# Creating an array of objects with for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

**I want to create an array of objects with `for` loop using values in another array.**

*Code Snippet below* generates `5` values, instead of `6` (as required)

```js
function generateArray() {
    var names = ["Fariz", "Falisha", "Mami", "Defina", "Fiska", "Papi"];
    var newObj = [];

    for (i = 0; i < names.length - 1; i++) {
        newObj[i] = {
            name: names[(Math.floor(Math.random() * (names.length)))],
            age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 40),
            communication: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
            skill: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
            experience: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
        }
    }

    return newObj;
}

console.log(generateArray());
```

> **How do I generate as many values as present in `names` array ?**

Comment: Seems to properly generate 5 random objects to me. If you want 6 objects, just increase the iterations by one.

Comment: Which one that you test? the php code is working but the javascript function code is not.

Comment: Just press "Run code snippet". Your code already works.

Comment: wait, how come it works when press run code snippet. I tried to do it in chrome it didn't work...

Comment: Yes, turns out my code did work, thank you everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Resolution** - Replace `i < names.length - 1` with `i < names.length`

The condition for executing the code block in `for` loop is wrong.
*Your code works fine, just generates 1 less result than needed.*

[MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) on how `for` works.

```js
function generateArray() {
    names = ["Fariz", "Falisha", "Mami", "Defina", "Fiska", "Papi"];
    newObj = [];

    for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        newObj[i] = {
            name: names[(Math.floor(Math.random() * (names.length)))],
            age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 40),
            communication: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
            skill: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
            experience: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
        }
    }

    return newObj;
}

console.log(generateArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
names = ["Fariz", "Falisha", "Mami", "Defina", "Fiska", "Papi"];

arob = [
    {
        name: names[(Math.floor(Math.random() * (names.length)))],
        age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 40),
        communication: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
        skill: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
        experience: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
    }, 
    {
        name: names[(Math.floor(Math.random() * (names.length)))],
        age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 40),
        communication: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
        skill: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
        experience: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
    }, 
    {
        name: names[(Math.floor(Math.random() * (names.length)))],
        age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 40),
        communication: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
        skill: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
        experience: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
    }, 
    {
        name: names[(Math.floor(Math.random() * (names.length)))],
        age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 40),
        communication: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
        skill: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
        experience: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
    }, 
    {
        name: names[(Math.floor(Math.random() * (names.length)))],
        age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 40),
        communication: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
        skill: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
        experience: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
    }, 
    {
        name: names[(Math.floor(Math.random() * (names.length)))],
        age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 40),
        communication: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
        skill: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
        experience: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
    }
];
```

Inside the for loop: `i < names.length;`, instead of `i < names.length - 1;`

```
function generateArray() {
    names = ["Fariz", "Falisha", "Mami", "Defina", "Fiska", "Papi"];
    newObj = [];

    for(i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
    newObj[i] = {
        name: names[(Math.floor(Math.random() * (names.length)))],
        age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 40),
        communication: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
        skill: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
        experience: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) }
    }

    return newObj;
}
```

This returns an array with all 6 objects.